# Modify Checked-Out Document

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have checked out a document from SharePoint in Office 365 and edited it in Word. I then saved and closed Word without checking the document back in again.

It shows that I have checked it out but when I try to edit the document it says I can't because it is checked out (by me).

Is there a way to resolve this without checking the document in and then out again or discarding the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the word doc in local drive first. Make your changes and upload document in library. SharePoint will ask you to override the file, give yes. And your file changes will be uploaded in it with out check in/ check out.